# EntityType ''IdentityUserRole' has no key defined error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

Working with entity framework code first.

Trying to use the IdentityRole id as a foreign key to a custom class.

the relationship is correct but when I try to add data to my custom table i get this error.

> EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for
>   this EntityType. IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no
>   keys defined.

Code:

**Custom table/class**

```
public class UserRoleAccess
{
    [Key]
    public long UserRoleAccessId { get; set; }

    public string UserRoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationRole ApplicationRole { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int UserRoleAccessType { get; set; }
}
```

**IdentityRole**:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleAccess> UserRoleAccess { get; set; }
}
```

**Bindings**:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();


        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleAccess>().ToTable("UserRoleAccess");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(p => p.Person)
            .WithMany(b => b.Users);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(p => p.Person)
            .WithMany(b => b.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });


    }
```

Relationship in db(correct):

[image]

Tried creating an id property and setting a `[Key]` attribute but it did not work:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRoleAccess> UserRoleAccess { get; set; }
}
```

Run this code when adding data:

```
    public static void CreateUserRoleAccess(string name, int type, string id)
    {

        using (var context = new UserRoleAccessContext())
        {
            var userRoleAccess = new UserRoleAccess();

            userRoleAccess.ApplicationRole = new ApplicationRole { Id = id };

            userRoleAccess.UserRoleId = id;
            userRoleAccess.IsActive = true;

            userRoleAccess.UserRoleAccessType = type;

            userRoleAccess.Name = name;

            context.UserRoleAccess.Add(userRoleAccess);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

IdentityRole class:

[IdentityRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613249(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: We don't use new keyword before ObjectType, do we?

    public new string Id { get; set; }

Comment: @Waleed something resharper added. how is your comment helping?
With or wihout the new keyword before the property It still does not work

Comment: Can you post the IdentityRole class? You have a mapping to the IdentityRole key in your model builder

Comment: @matthijsb it is the built in Ef class : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613249(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: The error message states that the error is about entity IdentityUserRole, not about IdentityRole. Your mappings do not define the relationships between this entity and other entities, so EF is probably creating implicitly the relations for this entity. Is a PK generated in the DB in "UserRoles" table? Could you show the code of entity IdentityUserRole?

Comment: @Diana https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613252(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Perhaps the physical key is not generated as the key you specified in the mappings. Can you look at the keys (primary or otherwise) existing in the physical table UserRoles?

Answer (score 2):

So, you are using `MVC 5` with `ASP.NET Identity 2.0`. I guess your project has the Nuget package for `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` and the right tables have been created in your database.

Perhaps your problem is because you are redefining the mappings for the standard Identity tables. Do you really need to map explicitly the table names and keys? I would try to keep the original mappings, and only add explicit mappings for your custom entities and fields. 
I think you don't need the ToTable mappings, as the base entities have a mapping somewhere in its code, and your entities extend them.

A couple of questions:

- What is the meaning of `UserRoleAccess.UserRoleId`? Is it a user id, or a role id? If it is meant to contain the UserRole id, it is a composed key, not a single value, so it is not likely that a String property would do. Perhaps you should rename it.
- What do you want to do exactly in the method `CreateUserRoleAccess`: adding a new `UserRoleAccess` for a role and user that already exist and are already related (that is, the `UserRole` relation already exists)? Or either adding a new `UserRole` and `UserRoleAccess` for a user and role that already exist but are not related? I assume you do not want to create the Role or the User at this point, they already exist, am I wrong?
- Anyway, in your CreateUserRoleAccess method, in this line:

  ```
  userRoleAccess.ApplicationRole = new ApplicationRole { Id = id };
  ```

  Unless you are creating a new Role in this same moment you should do a `Find` or other Linq query and get the existing Role from the context. Perhaps just changing this would make your code work:

  ```
  //userRoleAccess.ApplicationRole = new ApplicationRole { Id = id };
  userRoleAccess.ApplicationRole = context.Roles.Find(id) as ApplicationRole;
  ```

I created a MVC project and tried your code with several changes:

I did not include any explicit EF bindings or mappings, just to try with the original Identity model and see if it works.

I extended Identity DbContext just adding a DbSet for UserRoleAccess:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual IDbSet<UserRoleAccess> UserRoleAccesses { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

After adding your custom entities ApplicationRole and UserRoleAccess, generating a migration and updating the database I got the same UserRoleAccess table than you, but also a new column Discriminator in the Roles table:

[image]

This means EF is using TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) when you extend the `IdentityRole` entity with your `ApplicationRole` entity. They share the table. This is implicit, no need to write bindings (in fact, unneeded explicit bindings tend to interfere).

So, if your roles table is missing this field this can be a probable cause for you error.

I run the MVC web, and created a new user with the Register link in the page header. I run the following code (by adding it to the index controller), and it worked:

```
    public void CreateUserRoleAccess(string name, int type, string id)
    {
        //Insert role (run only once)
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var role = new ApplicationRole { Id = id, Name = "Role1" };
            var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault<ApplicationUser>();
            //user.Roles.Add(role);
            role.Users.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = role.Id, UserId = user.Id });

            context.Roles.Add(role);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var userRoleAccess = new UserRoleAccess();

            //userRoleAccess.ApplicationRole = new ApplicationRole { Id = id };
            userRoleAccess.ApplicationRole = context.Roles.Find(id) as ApplicationRole;

            //Is this a userId or a roleId? Does not seem OK to assign id param here
            userRoleAccess.UserRoleId = id;
            userRoleAccess.IsActive = true;

            userRoleAccess.UserRoleAccessType = type;

            userRoleAccess.Name = name;

            context.UserRoleAccesses.Add(userRoleAccess);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Note that I create first a new Role with a different context scope, to make sure the Role exists when I get to the interesting code. I use that role later getting it from the context.

Hope this helps. I can send you the whole solution code if you want.

EDIT - UserRoleAccess table:

[image: UserRoleAccess table]

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserRoleAccesses",
            c => new
                {
                    UserRoleAccessId = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserRoleId = c.String(),
                    IsActive = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    UserRoleAccessType = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ApplicationRole_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserRoleAccessId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.ApplicationRole_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationRole_Id);
```

Useful links:

[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) - I created the simple MVC solution using this info.

[ASP.NET Identity, extract from book Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.apress.com/files/extra/ASP_NET_Identity_Chapters.pdf)

Comment: Vote up for effort! Thank you! Although I am not sure you compleatly understood what I wanted to do. Could you display an image of how your
UserRoleAccess table looks like? it seems to me that you have a forein key from the AspNetUsers table and the AspnetRole table. I only wish to have a key attribute from the aspNetRoles table.  in the CreateUserRoleAccess method the id attrbite us an id of a role that already exists. And I will try you attempt by finding the id as you suggested.

Comment: You are welcome! I added the UserRoleAccess table to the answer. There is a foreign key from the AspNetRoles table, not from the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: So what you want is to use the property UserRoleId as the foreign key field and ApplicationRole as the navigation property? You can do that with the ForeignKey attribute, like this: `[ForeignKey("UserRoleId")]
        public virtual ApplicationRole ApplicationRole { get; set; }`. You can put the attribute either in ApplicationRole property or in UserRoleId property, just the parameter has to be the other property name.

Comment: If you do that the ApplicationRole_Id field will no longer be automatically generated (as the field UserRoleId will be used in the foreign key). I recommend changing the name of UserRoleId to ApplicationRoleId, for clarity.

Comment: If you prefer fluent mappings to annotations you can do it instead with this code in OnModelCreating method:             `modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoleAccess>().HasRequired(ura => ura.ApplicationRole)
                .WithMany().HasForeignKey(ura => ura.UserRoleId);`